Can I use my iPhone as a modem with a TP-Link extender?
I want to use my iPhone as a modem with my TP-Link RE705X Range Extender/Access Point. Can I connect my iPhone to the RE705X's Ethernet port using a USB-C to Ethernet adapter? or even Wi-Fi.
My goal is to share my iPhone's mobile hotspot connection with the TP-Link, allowing it to extend internet access to other devices connected to the RE705X.
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

There’s no obvious reason why it wouldn’t work. Have you tried it?

Your iPhone can share the hotspot with multiple devices all by itself. The total throughput is set by the speed of the cell signal.

I wish homepod could easily connect/switch to my iPhone hotspot
